# Laravel: How to get count of total Comments of total Posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, laravel-5.7

I have 10000 posts and each post have many comments. I need to calculate all comments count when i take posts.

```
[
    'post_1' => [
        'comments' => [
            'comment_1' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_2' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_3' => 'trst comment',
        ],
    ],
    'post_2' => [
        'comments' => [
            'comment_1' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_2' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_3' => 'trst comment',
        ],
    ],
    'post_3' => [
        'comments' => [
            'comment_1' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_2' => 'trst comment',
            'comment_3' => 'trst comment',
        ],
    ],
]
```

there are total 9 comments. i want get this count.

In laravel is possible to get count of hasMany relation of one row

```
Post::first()->comments()-count()
```

I need like this:

```
Post::get()->comments()-count()
```

i dont want use foreach because my server may get down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do in at least two ways.

- Taking advantage of the posts that you might have already loaded [counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
$total = $posts->sum('comments_count');
```

- Counting directly from the `Comment` model (in your case, I'll go for this approach):

```php
$total = Comment::count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must go in a different way:

```
Comment::whereNotNull('post_id')->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Post::withcount('comment')->where('post_id', $post_id)->get();
```

Try This One.

Answer (score 1):

```
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
$total = $posts->sum('comments_count');
```

OR

```
$total = Comment::all()->count();
```